# .Net MAUI use multi Shell by Flyout page goes blank

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I create a demo app by Net MAUI, using Flyout to navigate to three Shell page. In Windows is good, but in android, the page goes to blank.

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HHKk.png)

[go in again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE7pA.png)

and debug output says `MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead`

in AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="NexDroid.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NexDroid"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:NexDroid.Pages"
    xmlns:debug="clr-namespace:NexDroid.Pages.Debug"
    xmlns:parametes="clr-namespace:NexDroid.Pages.Parameters"
    FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Connect}" />
    <FlyoutItem Title="操作" Route="MainPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="调试">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate debug:DebugShell}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="参数">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate parametes:ParametersShell}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

in MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="NexDroid.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:NexDroid.Pages"
    xmlns:operation="clr-namespace:NexDroid.Pages.Operation"
    >
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="点动" Route="Operation/Jog">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate operation:Jog}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="拖拽" Route="Operation/Drag">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate operation:Drag}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

is there something wrong?

is there i using wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In AppShell.xaml, you can change to this:

```
    ...
    <Shell.TabBarIsVisible>false</Shell.TabBarIsVisible>
    <FlyoutItem Title="操作">
        <Tab Title="点动">
            <ShellContent Title="点动" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate operation:Jog}" />
            <ShellContent Title="拖拽" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate operation:Drag}" />
        </Tab>
        <ShellContent Title="调试" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate debug:DebugShell}" />
        <ShellContent Title="参数" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate parametes:ParametersShell}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    ...
```

Comment: @FanWei For more information, you can refer to [Create a .NET MAUI Shell app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/create?view=net-maui-7.0) by official.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your mainpage must be a ContentPage and not a Shell as you already have a shell in your app.

If you need different tabs to mainpage, and at the same time you need to get rid off the initial tabs you have to think about **how the user will go back** to the initial tabs. But if you want all the tabs to be visible both the initial tabs and the additional tabs of the mainpage, maybe is better to redesign the ui and **include bottom and top tabs**, so all the tabs will be visible to the user. Check the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: thanks for answer, i have already changed my project with no Shells